# Eclipse Juno: How to change background of code folding regions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I'm currently using Eclipse Juno (the latest version as of Aug 30, 2012). I switched to a dark theme using Eclipse Color Theme plugin.

I modified some background colors to match this dark theme. However, I can never find an option to change the back ground of the code folding regions (the space between line numbers and the code).

Please help me to change this background color!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using **Eclipse-Juno** on **Ubuntu** with the Dark Juno theme installed by doing the following:

- Click on **Window->Preferences** to open up your **Preferences** panel
- Open up the tab for the language you are using.  For me this was C/C++
- Goto **Folding**, and then uncheck **"Enable folding when opening a new editor"**.
- Click *Apply* and *OK*.

[image]

Now go back to your editor, and close and reopen any editors that you may have open (restarting Eclipse should also work).  The default code folding will be gone, along with the white background.

You can re-enable code folding at any time (with a black background) by typing **CTRL + NUMPAD_DIVIDE**.

[image]

Comment: Or you can use a context menu of a breakpoint panel to enable folding

Answer (score 0):

To fix this open the following file in a text editor:

```
org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

Once open look for the following line:

```
printMarginColor=101,101,101
```

The numbers represent the current color of the margin in RGB format.  Simply change the color to your desired color, save and close the editor.  Save and close any editor tabbed windows in Eclipse and re-open them .

If you are in Linux the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` file will be located in the following location:

```
~/[your workspace folder]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
```

Comment: What the OP is talking about is not the print margin.